# How do I select only two of three imgs within the same div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

The code is as follows:

```
<div id="compv-navbar">
        <a href="#"><img src="image1.png" id="icon1"></a> | 
        <a href="#"><img src="image2.png" id="icon2"></a> | 
        <a href="#"><img src="image3.png" id="icon3"></a> | 
        <span id="view_name"> 2-up</span>
    </div>
```

The jQuery is as follows:

```
$("#icon2")
            .qtip ({
                   content: 'Placeholder Text.',
                   show: 'mouseover',
                   hide: 'mouseout'
                  })
```

The above works, however, I want to select both 'icon2 & icon3'.

I tried doing `$('#icon2 #icon3')` and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('#icon2 , #icon3')
```

with comma separated

look :

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, you can use the [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector as follows:

```
// select all images after the first one
$("#compv-navbar img:gt(0)")
```

Answer (score 1):

try `$('#icon2, #icon3')`

`,` can be used for combining selectors

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You can try using -

```
$('#icon2, #icon3')
```

or

```
$('#icon2').add('#icon3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to comma sepperate multiple elements:

```
$('#icon2, #icon3')
```

as good as

```
$('#icon2').add('#icon3')
```

as good as

```
$('#compv-navbar').find('img:gt(0)')
```